# How to Embed the Blob Video file in Quill JS

Tags: quill

I am trying to append the recorded video which is blob object into quill editor but the video which is appended in the editor is not playable.

Able to see only the blob object getting printed in the quill editor.  If i try to open the contents in the browser it is working fine. Any suggestions?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mtp5k.png)

Answer (score 1):

well,according to [this issue](https://github.com/quilljs/quill/issues/1857),
I think you maybe need to overwrite the video module's sanitize method to make it work,for image it can work like this:

```
var Image = Quill.import('formats/image')
Image.sanitize = function(url) {
    return url
}
```

so as I guess, following things maybe useful:

```
var Video = Quill.import('formats/video')
Video.sanitize = function(url) {
    return url
}
```

and you may need provide blob url to make it work